# what does "" mean in `--pretty=""` of git log

Tags: git

I learned a new option `--pretty=""`

```
$ git log --pretty=""  --name-only
Algorithms/GrokkingAlgorithms/grokkingAlgorithms.md
Untitled.md
_manual.md
drafts.md
```

what does `""` mean here?

I checked `--pretty=format` but found no `--pretty=""`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`--pretty=""` defines the output format to `""`. This means that for each commit you just get an empty string `""` as output.

The overall effect of your command is that you see a list of the changed files but without the rest of the information about a commit (like for example commit ID, author, date, commit text).